# PHP: Convert date string with milliseconds to time

Tags: php, date

I tried using [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to convert a string to a date, but apparently it can't handle milliseconds/microseconds or the meridian.

This returns false:

```
$date = strtotime('30-APR-13 01.31.50.584000000 PM');
```

How can I convert the above to a date?

Comment: timestamps in php are "**Seconds** since 01-01-1970 00:00:00". Meaning they wouldn't include sub-second precision. If you needed more precision, you would likely want to use the DateTime class.

Comment: createFromFormat with the `u` format but you'll lose the last 3 digits of the microseconds.

Comment: The linked question did have the answer.  I ended up using `DateTime::createFromFormat('d-M-y h.i.s.u A', '30-APR-13 01.31.50.584000000 PM');` to get what I needed.